# Excel - Find 2nd highest block average

Tags: excel, average

I want to find the 2nd highest block average. In the formula below, I am find the 3-hour block averages.

3-hour block average refers to finding the average of A1:A3, A4:A6, A7:A9 etc.

```
AVERAGE(OFFSET($G$3,(ROW($G3)-1)*3,0,3,1))
```

However, I don't want to find the average of the 3-hour block averages. I want to find the maximum 3-hour block average. How would I do that?

I've tried adding a `LARGE` in front, but since the `AVERAGE` already finds the average of each 3-hour block, that doesn't work.

Example:

[image]

I would average 3.6, 2.6, and 1.2 and get one value, then Calib, 2.5, 1.8, etc. When I reach the end, I want to find the second highest 3-block average.

Comment: I have no idea what "block average" means or what a "3-hour" one would be or how one would go about finding a "2nd highest" of either of those if they are related somehow. Please share some sample data, your desired results, and a better explanation of how to get to the desired result. (p.s. I just searched "Block Average" and it's totally a thing, so shows what I know. I still think it would be helpful for an explanation for us Excel-Expert-yet-Stats-Laymen)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53109436/edit) and give us sample data and expected outcome

Comment: I added some more info. Please see if it's more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a range of `A1:A21`, **array formula****:

`=LARGE(IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(A1,3*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&INT(ROWS(A1:A21)/3)))-1),,3)),""),1)`

Change `LARGE`'s *k* parameter (1 here) as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Can you explain the `&INT` part?

When I try to apply this to a larger array, I'm getting #DIV/0 when use an array formula and a negative value when I do not. I've tried changing the range to make it divisible by 3, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. See example file here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tmASi9Rj8o5uzb3sKTaKyckayFBrLnCe

Comment: I realize that the error occurs when many cells in a row have text in them and therefore, the average cannot be calculated. How can I skip the cells if there are 4 or more text cells in a row?

Comment: Amended to account for such cases.